# How to plot this graph?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
total_income = df.groupby('genres')['gross'].sum()
average_income = df.groupby('genres')['gross'].mean()

total_income.plot.bar(label="Total Income", color = 'r')
average_income.plot.bar(label="Average Income")

plt.xlabel("Genres")
plt.ylabel("Dollars (Gross)")
plt.yscale("log")
```

Here's my code that plots the sum and average of gross by the genres of movies. The problem is when I plot the graph, it gives me a complete black graph. I believe it is due to the length of words in the genres because it contains multiple genres.

How Can I fix this so it shows the graph and it's genres? I need assistance.

Comment: If use my solution in your previous answer output is same? Problem is with labels only?  What is your desired output if have many categories?

Comment: I want it to show the graph with the genre showing something like this:

Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller  

;split genres along the "|" delimiter for movies with mutliple genres

Comment: @jezrael And yes. I used your way it produces the same output

Comment: @jezrael So like this?: https://hastebin.com/hanagajuki.go

Comment: It looks nice, how does it work?

Comment: @jezrael I'm getting an error https://snag.gy/QIsplg.jpg

Comment: Hmmm, before `splitted` add `df = df.dropna(subset=['genres']).reset_index(drop=True)` for remove all values from `NaN`s in `genres` and reset index.

Comment: @jezrael Thank You! It works!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `list`s, then get [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for `length`.

Last create new `DataFrame` by `constructor` with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'genres':['Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller','Comedy|Crime|Drama','Comedy|Crime','Drama|Thriller','Drama','Comedy|Crime'],
                   'gross':[10,20,30,40,50,60]})

print (df)
                        genres  gross
0  Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller     10
1           Comedy|Crime|Drama     20
2                 Comedy|Crime     30
3               Drama|Thriller     40
4                        Drama     50
5                 Comedy|Crime     60
```

---

```
splitted = df['genres'].str.split('|')
l = splitted.str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({'gross': np.repeat(df['gross'], l), 'genres':np.concatenate(splitted)})
print (df)
     genres  gross
0    Comedy     10
0     Crime     10
0     Drama     10
0  Thriller     10
1    Comedy     20
1     Crime     20
1     Drama     20
2    Comedy     30
2     Crime     30
3     Drama     40
3  Thriller     40
4     Drama     50
5    Comedy     60
5     Crime     60

d = {'mean':'Average','sum':'Total'}
df1 = df.groupby('genres')['gross'].agg(['sum','mean']).rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
          Total  Average
genres                  
Comedy      120       30
Crime       120       30
Drama       120       30
Thriller     50       25

df1.plot.bar()
```